# server.servlet.session.timeout not taking effective in Boot 2.1.4.Release

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying out the `server.servlet.session.timeout` property, but timeout doesn't seem to work. I've setup a simple Boot app:

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9595
server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
# Also tried server.servlet.session.timeout=1m
# Also tried to combine with server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=60s
```

Typical SpringBoot configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SessionTimeoutDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SessionTimeoutDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and a simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class SomeControler {


    @PostMapping(value = "/data") 
    public ResponseEntity<String> postData(@RequestBody String body) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(300*1000); //wait 5 minutes
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
}
```

Then try out like:

```
date; curl -d "This is the data" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9595/data; date
```

The app actually waits for 5 full minutes, not timeout after 1 minute as expected

```
**Wed Apr 10 12:59:17 AEST 2019**
* About to connect() to localhost port 9595 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9595 (#0)
> POST /data HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:9595
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
> 
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 202 
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 03:04:17 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
**Wed Apr 10 13:04:17 AEST 2019**
```

Can anyone sppt what I'm missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you creating the session? With the code you have shared I'm afraid a session would be created.

Comment: session timeout isn't connection timeout... You are mixing things up.

Comment: @M.Deinum: yep, you're right. Wrong testing method.